# How did the Jedi deal with trainees who lacked hands and thus couldn't use a lightsaber the traditional way?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

Given the tremendous amount of species in the Star Wars universe, there have to be at least a few without hands, or comparable grasping appendages.

Comment: Now I wanna see a Tines Jedi.

Comment: Like this? https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFo5X.png

Comment: Thought Kazdan Paratus might count with his Doc Ock-esque droid arms but there's another Jedi of the same species who got by just fine with his own stubby limbs.

Comment: Not an answer, but [Ooroo](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Ooroo) might provide some information.

Comment: Lightsaber skills are far from being the only skills, a padawan learns during his training. Lightsaber combat is not included in the padawan trial, but interestingly it's included in the Jedi Initiate Trials.

Comment: One of the unfortunate things about the prequels is that Jedi and Jedi Knight became synonymous.  Yoda should not be using a lightsaber - he's wise in the force but just isnt built for enforcement Knight role.  Likewise OT Palpatine sneered at lightsabers as a Jedi weapon.  He had his arms as deadly weapons just like Joe Dirt